# Интеграция платежной системы LiqPay с помощью API

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ecommerce, liqpay

Есть интернет-магазин на Django. Хочу подключить к нему платежную систему **LiqPay** через [API](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/home/).
В документации сказано, как формировать json-данные. Я создал класс, который формирует json-данные и кодирует их с помощью `base64` и `hashlib`. Вот он:

```
import json
import base64
import hashlib

class Json_Data():
    
    def __init__(self, order, cart):
        self.order = order
        #order_id = order.id
        #total_price = cart.get_total_price()
        self.cart = cart
        self.data = {"public_key": "i5852363076", "version": 3, "action": "pay", 
                     "amount": str(self.cart.get_total_price()), "currency": "UAH", "description":"Оплата 
                      заказа", "order_id": str(self.order.id}
        self.private_key = '***********************************'
        
    def json_data_value(self):
        self.encode_data = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(self.data).encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
        print(self.data)
        print(self.encode_data)
        
    def json_signature_value(self):
        signature = (self.private_key + self.encode_data + self.private_key).encode("utf-8")
        encode_signature = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(signature).digest()).decode("ascii")
        print(encode_signature)
```

Далее я вызываю этот класс, в части **views.py**, которая формирует заказ и отсылаю уже готовые закодированные данные на страницу **pay_online.html**. Вот она:

```
if order.way_of_delivery == 'НП':
        json_data = Json_Data(order, cart)
        data = json_data.json_data_value()
        signature = json_data.json_signature_value()
        return render(request, 'order/pay_online.html', {'data': data, 'signature': signature})
```

Код в **pay_online.html** выглядит вот так (форма взята из документации LiqPay):

```
<form method="POST" class="order-form" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" accept 
    charset="utf8">
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value={{ data }}/>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value={{ signature }}/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Заказать"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Но когда меня перекидывает на страницу платежа, я получаю ошибку `INVALID_JSON`...

Также я попытался использовать на странице **pay_online** платежный виджет вместо формы сверху:

```
<div id="liqpay_checkout"></div>
      <script>
          window.LiqPayCheckoutCallback = function() {
          LiqPayCheckout.init({
              data: "{{ data }}",
              signature: "{{ signature }}",
              embedTo: "#liqpay_checkout",
              mode: "embed" // embed || popup,
                  }).on("liqpay.callback", function(data){
              console.log(data.status);
              console.log(data);
              }).on("liqpay.ready", function(data){
                  // ready
              }).on("liqpay.close", function(data){
                  // close
          });
        };
      </script>
      <script src="//static.liqpay.ua/libjs/checkout.js" async></script>
```

Когда я передаю сюда свои `data` и `signature`, то виджет просто не отображается. Когда я просто копирую скрипт виджета с документации LiqPay, не вставляю туда свои `data` и `signature`, то виджет отбражается коректно.

Я так понимаю, проблема, скорее всего в том, что я неправильно формирую json-данные и передаю их также не верно.

Обьясните, кто может, как вообще правильно интегрировать эту платежную систему и в чем, конкретно здесь, мои ошибки?

Comment: Исходя из моего опыта интеграции с платёжными системами - ошибка скорее всего в неправильно сформированном JSON.
Знаю помощь от этого комментария - такая себе, но развернуть ваш код у себя - не имея ключей к API, идея такая себе.

Проверяйте JSON, структуру его и кодировку (если она нужна).

Answer (score 1):

для пайтона есть библиотека, вот страница на гитхабе https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-python

Там есть и о том как прикрутить виджет к Django.

также тут есть примеры ее использования https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/p2p_credit/doc

Виджет

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    liqpay = LiqPay(settings.LIQPAY_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY)
    params = {
        'action': 'pay',
        'amount': '100',
        'currency': 'USD',
        'description': 'Payment for clothes',
        'order_id': 'order_id_1',
        'version': '3',
        'sandbox': 0, # sandbox mode, set to 1 to enable it
        'server_url': 'https://test.com/billing/pay-callback/', # url to callback view
    }
    signature = liqpay.cnb_signature(params)
    data = liqpay.cnb_data(params)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'signature': signature, 'data': data})
```

И важно то, что ваши методы класса Json_Data, ничего не возвращают, а вы этого ждете

```
data = json_data.json_data_value()
signature = json_data.json_signature_value()
```

И `data` и `signature` будут `None`. В общем используйте готовую библиотеку и будет вам счастье